# Creating a [url="link"]title[!url] style preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I really can't figure out how create a preg_replace for this:

```
[url="link"]title[!url]
```

gives me:

```
<a href="link">title</a>
```

i was trying this:

```
$patterns = array();
$replacements = array();
$patterns[0] = '/\[b\]/';
$patterns[1] = '/\[\!b\]/';
$patterns[2] = '/\[url="([*]+)"\]([*]+)\[\!url\]/';
$replacements[0] = '<strong>';
$replacements[1] = '</strong>';
$replacements[2] = '<a href="$1">$2</a>';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```

The [b], [!b] works just fine... but i can't solve the [url] problem... :(

Comment: An href attribute probably has more characters than you are looking for. It should also be written something like this. `([a-z0-9A-Z_.-]+)`

Comment: Is this BBCode?  There is a BBCode extension for PHP already. http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace('/\[url="(.+?)"\](.+?)\[\!url\]/', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $string)`

this will assume you don't want to check for invalid url characters. your example fails to pickup a lot of characters that would be valid in a url, and thus break the functionality you're seeking. here's a more complete version:

`preg_replace('/\[url="([A-Za-z0-9\-._~:\/?#[\]@!$@&()\'*+,;=%]+)"\](.+)\[\!url\]/', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $string)` is actually a more complete, [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986/) compliant regular expression.

Comment: `.` means any character (except whitespace, based on default regex flags). `+` normally means one or more of previous item, so in this case, any character at least once. We add the `?` to the `+` so it's lazy, meaning it won't try to grab the next `]`, as that would normally match "any" character via `.`. I think the `?` i probably redundant, as it catch it as part of your whole string. Actually, it would break if you had a "]" in your URL. I've added a more accurate regex in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to put your character matches in brackets

```
\[url="([a-z0-9A-Z_.-]+)"\]([a-z0-9A-Z\s_.-]+)\[\!url\]
```

---

AFTER QUESTION EDIT

try this

```
\[url="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[\!url\]
```

Comment: i will update my code for the 'real' thing i have that should help u to figure out. With your example i can't achieve success